# How to delete a google apps script service

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried a particular app script (Gmail Meter) by adding it to a spreadsheet. Even though I think I deleted the spreadsheet (manually checked through past spreadsheets), it did not quite delete the service and I keep getting alerts (I revoked its permissions somewhere and I keep getting notifications that the service requires authorization).

How do I delete this service permanently?

Comment: The answer here worked for me, but after I did this I found the document in the "Trash" folder.  For future readers, you might try removing it from the trash also, maybe that will delete the triggers, or at least stop them from working.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Strange. Maybe, Try checking if the trigger is still there:

Open a spreadsheet then go to Tools -> Script Editor, then on the editor window go to Edit -> All your triggers... and see if the gmail meter method is still listed there. If so, delete it.

Comment: Yep. That did it for me. Although I had to ask on google's product forum to find the answer. (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/1bdQnnDyhiA/LA3edw3w-7MJ) Just came back to SO to help flesh out any questions there were on the subject as I didn't find answers my first pass.

Comment: Thanks, the first part is now "tools->script editor", not "tools->spreadsheet editor"... or at least it was for me, as of Oct 2013.  Took a bit to find it.

Comment: I deleted a script and couldn't figure out why it was still triggering, this fixed it. Thanks!!

Comment: @KostaKontos: you can edit answers and propose the change! I've just done that for you.

Answer (score 7):

Find the URL to the script url in the script editor i.e:

https://script.google.com/macros/d/MS3-PFwnUdYw7_bQF3y8BJte_1Q7n6BNa/edit

Remove edit from url and replace with manage/uninstall

https://script.google.com/macros/d/MS3-PFwnUdYw7_bQF3y8BJte_1Q7n6BNa/manage/uninstall

Click uninstall and that should be it!

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense in regard to that question... the author had deleted the spreadsheet containing the script. He had no way to find any script URL!  See other answer that brought a real solution.

Comment: Actually, this answer helped me delete a script, which I had erased previously, but it was still published. I just added the `/manage/uninstall` at the end of it, and it worked perfectly. Of course, this would only work if you have the URL to the script.

Answer (score 3):

After you delete the script, look for it in the trash folder and delete it from there as well. This has worked for me; no other steps are necessary.