# Deleted script, no triggers, still getting emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I deleted a google apps script from docs (Gmail Snooze), but I keep getting a message every day:

Start             Function  Error Message                      Trigger
6/9/12 12:49 AM   myFunction    We're sorry, a server error        time-based
                                occurred. Please wait a 
                                bit and try again.

I've already tried creating a new script, going to Resources > All Your Triggers, and nothing is there.

Is there a better way to get rid of these error messages than creating a new filter in gmail to auto delete them?

Answer (score 2):

Have you also tried deleting the spreadsheet from the Trash in Google Docs?

Answer (score 0):

There have been some reported problems around deleting triggers. You may want to add a comment on this [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1184).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

> Open a spreadsheet then go to tools-spreadsheet editor, then on the
>   editor window go to Resources->All your triggers... and see if the
>   trigger is still listed there. If so, delete it.

Source: [How to delete a google apps script service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459410/how-to-delete-a-google-apps-script-service)

Answer (score -1):

There might be an update to the interface. Triggers are now accessible trough different menu. 
Open [script.google.com](http://script.google.com) and open any project or create a new one if you don't have any projects. Then go to **Edit>All your triggers** and switch off the ones you don't need.