# Deleted Google Apps spreadsheet that had a trigger. Error emails coming in, and cant get to trigger manager

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script

I had a spreadsheet with a trigger in it, which I have deleted. Its the only spreadsheet I ever used any scripts in, so I'm sure it's whats causing it.

Now I get an email every day titled:

Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Not found

And its huge, full of line after line of:

We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

There is a link in the email to the trigger manager: https://docs.google.com/macros/triggers?lib=MAT_7pjOEI5hz78DwYxi4-p52yylnQMZB

But that page gives me:

We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

How do I delete this trigger, so I stop getting these emails?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds more like a bug on googles internal servers then something that SO will be able to help you with. Try reaching out to google and report the bug.

Comment: Please see [this related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459410/how-to-delete-a-google-apps-script-service) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You might still have the document available in the Trash, so you *may* be able to recover it and access it normally to remove the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same thing and was surprised to not see an answer here.

It's easy enough to fix, even if you've not got the original spreadsheet. Just got into Script Editor -> Resources -> All your triggers.

Then you can delete the offending trigger. Job done!