# How to Stop Orphaned Triggers

Tags: google-apps-script

Interesting use case:
1. Script 1 with ScriptApp trigger management associated as an image link in a Google Site
2. Created a new instance of the script under a new account and update the image link
3. Deleted the container script 1 within the Google Site
4. A user visited the Google Site to invoke the script, but the page was cached pointing to the previous script 1.
5. The on-error trap emails are being emailed to me every time the "deleted" script runs.

How do I delete or stop these triggers?

Comment: Was the trigger manually or automatically? Is the trigger running from your account or of another user?

Comment: Automatic via the ScriptApp service. Running as the user. The script was not published.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a google apps script service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459410/how-to-delete-a-google-apps-script-service)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the user that installed the trigger you could ask them to do to the "All my triggers" menu item in the script editor, find the trigger and delete it.

Comment: And if you don't know the user?

Answer (score 0):

In the on-error email, there is a link to manage triggers. Make sure that the triggers are really gone. I had this issue with a set of shared spreadsheets, where I thought I had removed all the triggers, but my partner still had some enabled.

Comment: Actually it is not an error from the script but a trapped error that I send to my self.

Comment: If you open a script project, under Resources > "All your triggers...", do you still have any triggers set?
If I understand correctly, people are viewing a cached version of the page that runs the old script, right?

Comment: The script project was deleted. Later, a user was able to still run it via a cached Google Site page. Why it worked when I deleted it is a mystery. As a result, the script schedules a repeating trigger. How do I delete triggers for another user when the script project is deleted?

Comment: Is the from or reply-to email of the user in the emails you get? You may be able to contact the user that way.

Answer (score 0):

In the Script Editor, You can also check for a project's triggers programmatically, then work with that trigger and it's source:

```
// Get triggers  
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

// Loop through each trigger
triggers.forEach(function(trigger) {

    // Get the id
    var id = trigger.getTriggerSourceId();

    // You can then use that id to get the related form or a sheet. E.g. :
    var ss = SpreadSheetApp.openById(id);

    // You can also work with the trigger (i.e. delete it)
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);

  });
```

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app for more