# Google Apps Script keeps running after trigger removed (multiple users)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I have a fairly simple Google Apps Script that runs every time an answer to a Google Form is submitted (by using "on form submit" trigger). The script does some simple manipulations and updates a Google SpreadSheet. Recently I needed to change that script to run manually and not on form submit, so I deleted the trigger. However the script still kept running on every form submit!

There are other users who might have the same trigger setup, since the spreadsheet and the code are shared. Is there a way to completely delete all the triggers for a particular script? In the meantime I just renamed the script and that has solved the issue, however this is a bad solution.

Search on stackoverflow did nothing, seemingly similar questions are resolved through clearing "Resources -> All your triggers...", which only does it for your user. Question is how to remove/edit all the triggers for the project, even from other users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Stop Orphaned Triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201847/how-to-stop-orphaned-triggers)

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Comment: Thank you for your comments. This is not the duplicate, since the topic you referenced deals with a deleted script, not a trigger. I did clarify the results of the research in the edit and updated the title.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to stop any orphaned Google Script.

1. Go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions
2. Click the script / project name you wish to uninstall
3. Next click Remove and you are done.

Comment: Amit, thank you for sharing this link. However, the issue is not an orphaned script. Issue is that triggers on other people's accounts are running the script. Is there a way to at least identify which accounts do that? Or, even better - to disable all the triggers for a given script, regardless on whose account they are? Thank you!