# Delete a google-apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a spreadsheet, and over the years I've been editing/adding scripts to this spreadsheet to extend functionality. While doing this, I inadvertently created some extra projects. Now when I click Tools -> Script Editor, it comes up with the following:
[image]

How do I delete "Copy of Character Data", and "Untitled project"? I'd like to keep the google spreadsheet around (As I'd like to keep its revision history).

I've tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459410/how-to-delete-a-google-apps-script-service), but to no avail. Going to "script.google.com" simply loaded my last script, and didn't give me some type of dashboard where I could remove individual scripts. I see no delete option anywhere, and there is no scripts that I could find in "drive.google.com".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the project you want to delete and when you are in you have the option to delete it (as long as you are the owner of the project).

[image]

Comment: [Delete project is not an option](http://i.imgur.com/pMFeulJ.png). Also, [I am owner of the spreadsheet](http://i.imgur.com/7CQcr3K.png).

Comment: I guess you misunderstood what I said, I probably wasn't clear enough. The projects to delete are the ones to get rid of , and that was exactly what you were asking for.

Comment: Your reply doesn't make sense

Comment: I beg your pardon ? Your question is about how to delete projects you don't want to keep, that's exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: And I'm telling you that the "Delete Project" link you're talking about doesn't exist in the dropdown menu.

Comment: then look at the revision history of the script, you should see the name of the owner of this script

Comment: Apparently, I copied it from someone else, and they're the original owner. I've deleted my other copies though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the option `Delete project`, that means those projects weren't created with the account you're logged in. Log in with that account or ask the person who created them to delete those projects.

Comment: How do I see who the owner is? As far as I know, I am the owner of this spreadsheet/script.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to get the owner of a bound script project. If another user with edit privileges create a new project with **File > New > Project** it gets associated to that account, the other editors won't be able to see/use option **File > Delete project**, **Resources > Developers Console Project**  or **Publish > Deploy as web app**. Can you ask the other editors if someone can see that option? That is totally independent if you're the owner of the Speadsheet.