# Is there a way to delete or leave a locked Google Cloud Project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I need to delete permanently a Google Workspace Organization (for a final customer). This organization have an active project in Google Cloud that definitevely locks deletation of Workspace Organization. The project has been created by the system called "apps-scripts".

The "apps-scripts" project was a container for scipts.google.com, that hosted a gsheet macro.

I cannot delete or leave this project on my own. It's system-wide impossible due to limitation on the right 'manage.resource.folderdelete' has been set to false by the old GSuite system. It protects well macro againts container deletation. It protects so well !

My question is ...
The Google Worskpace support (paid) team say that the problem is out of there scope.
The Google Cloud Commercial support said that only the (paid) Google Cloud Support can operate manually on project deletation.
The Google Cloud Customer Care support that only the (paid) Google Workspace support can operate on Gsuite locked project.

I tried to tell to each support, what the others said. Many screenshot. It seems, Google Workspace support and GCP Customer Care agreed, that i'm stuck in an abnormal and rare loop.

But (here comes my question ...) : Do the hell i have the only google account that :

- once a Google Gsuite organization has been corretly migrated to Google Workspace
- once migrated, a user generated a macro on gsheeet that needed the GCP apps-scripts in order to create a single script on script.google.com
- once has decided to leave

just can not ?

[image]

Comment: Of course, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317588/delete-a-google-apps-script doesn' help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP finally answer.
The "Folder Editor" IAM has not been replicated while GSuite/Workspace replication.

Done manually with the set-iam-policy on the organization wide folders.

In fact, the inherited Owner and Editor, doesn't allow ... folder deletion.